# Wondering how I can use a variable that is defined inside a def outside of the def and in the rest of my code

Tags: python, card

```
def start():
    playernum = int(input('Enter number of players: '))
    numberplayers = str(playernum)
    print("okay, dealing " + numberplayers + " hands")
start()

#getting player names
players = []
for i in range(playernum):
    players.append(input("Enter name of the player: "))
```

I want to be able to use the variable `playernum` again and throughout the code, how can I make it so this will be defined and usable.

Comment: Look at the *return* statement. Do not use *global*

Comment: you can declare the variable globally or use the global keyword

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return the value from your *start()* function:

```
def start():
    playernum = int(input('Enter number of players: '))
    print(f"okay, dealing {playernum} hands")
    return playernum

playernum = start()

#getting player names
players = []
for i in range(playernum):
    players.append(input("Enter name of the player: "))
```